# How do I prove this probability question?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Show that if $A\subset B\subset C\subset D$, then

$P(A\cap B\cap C\cap D)=P(A/B) \cdot P(B/C)\cdot P(C/D)\cdot P(D)$

Comment: The tag "conditional probability" makes me suspect that you must write $\mid$ instead of $/$. For this use \mid,

Comment: @Vera The question in my paper actually uses the slash. I merely copied what they wrote. So are they wrong? Sry I just tagged thinking it's conditional probability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- $P(C\mid D)P(D)=P(C\cap D)=P(C)$ since $C\subseteq D$ implies that $C=C\cap D$.
- $P(B\mid C)P(C)=P(B\cap C)=P(B)$ since $B\subseteq C$ implies that $B=B\cap C$.
- $P(A\mid B)P(B)=P(A\cap B)=P(A)$ since $A\subseteq B$ implies that $C=C\cap D$.
- $P(A)=P(A\cap B\cap C\cap D)$ since $A\subseteq B\subseteq C\subseteq D$ implies that $A=A\cap B\cap C\cap D$.